# Spring boot configuration - how to overwrite only specified properties

Tags: spring-boot, properties, default, reload

I've a spring boot application that is shipped with the default configuration inside the packed application.
so I can do the following:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:applicationame.some.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "file:${applicationame.some.properties.vmarg}", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class UIPropertiesConfigUsingClass
```

This way the application has the default configuration from the class path within the application,
but if I specify the `-Dapplicationame.some.properties.vmarg=PathToProperties` as VM argument on startup I can overwrite these properties.

But this has some disadvantages. If I specify it, I have to specify all the properties within the file otherwise they will be unspecified and I can change them only on application start not during run-time.

Is there a cheap solution  that would give me the opportunity to provide the properties file but only specify the properties that are actually different to the ones in the default?
And provide the automatic reload of the properties if they are changed during run-time, so that a restart is not needed?

Comment: there are various ways to do it. Take a look at this. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: @want2learn: but there I don't see this overwriteing ...